# PowerBI dataset usage

Tags: powerbi, dataset

I have iherited a few reports in powerbi and i encountered a problem with few of the data sets. Is there any easy way to check on what pages/visuals is dataset used?

I have lots of pages in my reports and don't like the idea of spending the day checking every single graph/table if it uses specific dataset.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.